# Matlab coder unsupported functions

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I'm trying to convert a piece of MATLAB code into C++ via MATLAB coder.  Many of the functions in the MATLAB code like `imread`, `imshow`, `normcorr2` are not supported by MATLAB coder.

What are some options to deal with this?  Would it be possible to rewrite these functions using C++ and insert them via MEX file?  Note I have very little experience with MATLAB, so I may be talking out of my rear.

Comment: Did you choose the Matlab Coder for a good reason? [Maybe the Compiler SDK is the better choice](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/223937-should-i-use-matlab-compiler-sdk-or-matlab-coder-to-integrate-my-matlab-applications-with-c-c). Users of the application are required to install the free matlab MCR but you don't have to reimplement anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea to provide C code to the coder is right, but mex does not work. Instead, you have to use `coder.ceval`.

Another option is `coder.extrinsic`, if you use it you tell the MATLAB coder not to generate code but rather call the function in MATLAB. If you do this, it obviously requires a MATLAB installation on the target system.

Comment: For coder.ceval , if the c code I'm providing is using a library (I'm trying to call opencv's imread in the c code to replace Matlab's imread), would that work?

Comment: Yes. You can specify additional libraries for linking.